# Issue with Contact Sharing rule for Site Guest User

Tags: sharing-rule

I create a public site with the following settings:

1. Enable "Assign new records created by Salesforce Sites guest users to a default owner in the org".
2. Set contact Internal/External Access to Private
3. Grant the Read and Create Contact permission for the site guest user.
4. Create a Share rule to Share Contact to the site guest user.

I create a visualforce page to test the access to Contact (*with sharing* is used in the controller). According to my test:

1. The site guest user can create a Contact
2. After the Contact is created, the owner is changed to the Site Admin user.
3. The Contact record is shared to the site guest user (readonly) however the site guest user CAN NOT query the Contact.

Does anyone know what's wrong with it? Any help is appreciated.

======== Visualforce page =======

```
<apex:page controller="TestAccessController">
<apex:form>
    <apex:actionStatus startText=" loading..." stopText="done" id="loadStatus"/>
    
    <apex:pageBlock id="mainBlock">
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>First Name</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputTextarea value="{!con.FirstName}" style="width:800px;height:100px;"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>Last Name</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputTextarea value="{!con.LastName}" style="width:800px;height:50px;" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>Email</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputTextarea value="{!con.Email}" style="width:800px;height:50px;" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons id="tokenButtons" location="both" rendered="true">
            <apex:commandButton id="GetContact" value="Get Contact" action="{!getContact}" status="loadStatus" reRender="mainBlock"/>
            <apex:commandButton id="SaveContact" value="Save Contact" action="{!saveContact}" status="loadStatus" reRender="mainBlock"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

======== Controller =======

```
public with sharing class TestAccessController {
    public Contact con{get;set;}

    public TestAccessController(){
        con = new Contact();
    }

    public PageReference saveContact(){
        
        try{
            insert con;
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Contact created'));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage()));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference getContact(){
        try{
            //"List has no rows..." error is thrown although the site guest user has read access to a Contact
            con = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email from Contact limit 1];
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage()));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image: Contact Sharing Rule]

UPDATE: I have tested with Contact and a custom object

1. For both: the site guest user can't query a record immediately after it is created. It is probably because the record sharing is executed asynchronously so it it takes a while before the site guest user can access it. This is quite bad because it does not allow to link a child object to a parent object which is not accessible at the time the child object is created.
2. After a while, the site guest user can query the custom object but can't query Contact.

Comment: How does your sharing rule look like. Can you add the screenshot please

Comment: I just added the screenshot.

Comment: If you are trying to implement the above 'With sharing' controller class in a sandbox with Winter 21 release, querying will not work. You should use 'Without sharing' context while executing a controller class in the 'Site Guest user' running user.

Comment: Thanks @ArnoldJr., unfortunately I have to use with sharing because it's in a managed package.

Comment: You might need to have a sub-class that uses 'Without sharing' and queries necessary records and returns them. Even I have done the same as the Salesforce support suggested for our similar use-case.

Comment: I have to remove the 'with sharing' from the class as a workaround.